# Regular Expression to find text between less than and greater than equal sign

Tags: php, regex, string

So I tried this regex:

```
$email = '';
preg_match('<.*?>', 'sadfas<email@email.com>', $email);
echo $email[0];
```

The target result is so to extract 'email@email.com' since it is between the < and > sign...but it did not work...

What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You forgot the regular expression delimiters (`/` is a popular delimiter). You should also use a sub-pattern to match only the address and not the `<>`:

```
preg_match('/<(.*?)>/', 'sadfas<email@email.com>', $email);
echo $email[1];
```

Alternatively, you could do a look-ahead and look behind to avoid using the sub-pattern:

```
preg_match('/(?<=<).*?(?=>)/', 'sadfas<email@email.com>', $email);
echo $email[0];
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to:

1. delimit your regular expression
2. create a capture group for the bits you want

Code:

```
<?php
$email = '';
preg_match('/<(.*?)>/', 'sadfas <email@email.com>', $email);
print_r($email);
?>
```

test:

```
% php foo.php
Array
(
    [0] => <email@email.com>
    [1] => email@email.com
)
```

Note how the actual field you want is in `$email[1]`

Answer (score 1):

Try this code instead:

```
preg_match('/<(.*)?>/', 'sadfas<email@email.com>', $email);
echo $email[1];
```

1. You need to wrap the results in parentheses to return the match.
2. Add the pattern delimiter to the PHP match (I use /)